# Which shuffle racing setting gives the most variety in the available cars?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

Currently when running shuffle racing in Gran Turismo, you can set the "base" performance points from 300 to 500 at 20 point increments. This controls the cars that are randomly assigned to all the racers.

At 300 points there appears to be a very limited handful of cars available with the same half dozen of cars making a regular appearance. Available cars also become limited as the setting approaches 500.

Does anyone know which setting gives the greatest variety of available cars? Is it PP400, or higher than that?